# Sprague–Grundy theorem in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph-theory, game-theory

I'm trying to implement the "[Sprague–Grundy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem)" in MATLAB. This theorem essentially tries to find the minimum excluded element in an array, for example in the array [0 1 3 4 5] the value would be 2. In addition to that, the function needs to be able to recurse along different rows in a matrix (in specific an adjacency matrix from graph theory) For example, if I had the adjacency matrix:

1 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0

0 1 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 0

If I used this matrix as an input, and the function started at the 5th row, then it would iterate across the row "0 0 1 0 0" and when it sees the 1 in the 3rd column, the function would recurse to the 3rd row, then recurse to the 4th, then the 2nd, and then the 1st.

What I'm having trouble with is doing recursion where the function input is a **matrix/array**. I think recursion is simple enough when the function input is an integer, but with a matrix/array I don't know how to "keep" track of the values and get the final array I want. This is my matlab code so far:

```
function [ y ] = S_Grundy( X,r,m )
%   Recursively finds the SG value given an adj matrix, 

Row_ones = find(X(r,:) == 1)
y=0.*size(Row_ones,2);

% if(numel(Row_ones)==0)
%     y(:)=0;
%     return
% end


for i=1:size(Row_ones,2)

    if(Row_ones(i) >= m) 
       y = S_Grundy(X,Row_ones(i),m);
    end
end

if (Row_ones(i) < m)

    for j=0:max(Row_ones)
        if(isempty(find(Row_ones==j)));%&&(isempty(find(Row_ones==0))))
            y(i)=j;
        else
            y(i)=777;

%                 if(isempty(find(Row_ones==j)))
%                     y(i)=j;
%                 end
            end    
        end

    end   
end
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the specific desired output for a specific input?

Comment: the output would be the "minimum excluded value"  For example, say we have a matrix and the integer input is 5. If the 5th row of the adj matrix is [1 0 0 0 1] then the program should check the 1st row and 5th row of the adj matrix, then if the 1st and 5th rows of the adj matrix are [0 0 0 0 0] and [0 0 0 0 0] (respecitvelty) then the output is 1, because the set of values in the 1st and 5th row are the set S={0}, so the minumum excluded value i.e. the smallest value NOT in the set is 1

Comment: does the graph in question have any special properties, e.g. is it acyclic? For a cyclic graph, using recursion wouldn't be a good idea, since you could get into an endless loop

Answer (score 0):

So, to rephrase your question, you're trying to find a vertex with a minimal index, such that it isn't reachable from the starting vertex, is that correct?

I wouldn't use recursion at all; I'd incrementally build the set of vertices reachable from the vertices reached so far, until I can't find any more.

```
graph = [1 0 0 0 0; 1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1 0; 0 1 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0]

start = 5

component = graph(start, :)
lastcomponent = zeros(1, 5)

while (sum(component) > sum(lastcomponent))
    lastcomponent = component
    component = sign(sum(graph(find(component == 1), :), 1) + lastcomponent)
endwhile

result = min(find(component == 0))
```

(One could probably write it better, I'm no matlab pro. But you should get the idea)